# Deploy a vue cli site to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I am trying to deploy a static website to an s3 bucket. I built my site using the [webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) from vue-cli

When I build the site there is a note that:

```
Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.
Opening index.html over file:// won't work.
```

Indeed there are no script tags in index.html but there is a comment that:

```
<!-- built files will be auto injected -->
```

If I add a path to the JS build file build/build.js I get that error that require cannot be found.

Is there a way to serve this site via s3? If so, how? Thank you

Comment: What command did you use to create the build?

Comment: `vue init webpack my-site-name`. I got a response for the github specific repo here: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/814

Comment: Using the standard webpack and not webpack-simple won't give you a single `dist/build.js` file in my experience.  You will end up with multiple files in your dist directory.  You need those and your index.html file for it to work on the server.